# Paytm JS Checkout issue in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, paytm

While integrating Paytm JS Checkout in asp.net C# application it is working fine in google chrome but in mozilla firefox payment popup window does not open and it gives the following error in mozilla console :
"Uncaught TypeError: window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.init is not a function"

```js
<div id="paytm-checkoutjs"></div>
<script type="application/html" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/merchantpgpui/checkoutjs/merchants/demoKey.js" onload="onScriptLoad();"> </script>

<script>
  function onScriptLoad(){
      var config = {
        "root": "",
        "flow": "DEFAULT",
        "data": {
        "orderId": "", /* update order id */
        "token": "", /* update token value */
        "tokenType": "TXN_TOKEN",
        "amount": "" /* update amount */
        },
        "handler": {
          "notifyMerchant": function(eventName,data){
            console.log("notifyMerchant handler function called");
            console.log("eventName => ",eventName);
            console.log("data => ",data);
          } 
        }
      };

      if(window.Paytm && window.Paytm.CheckoutJS){
          window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.onLoad(function excecuteAfterCompleteLoad() {
              // initialze configuration using init method 
              window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.init(config).then(function onSuccess() {
                  // after successfully updating configuration, invoke JS Checkout
                  window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.invoke();
              }).catch(function onError(error){
                  console.log("error => ",error);
              });
          });
      } 
  }
</script>
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please can you give us more information about your attempts? See the guidelines of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post great questions :)

Answer (score 0):

// Wrap inside **onLoad** and it will work fine.

```
if (window.Paytm && window.Paytm.CheckoutJS) {
  window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.onLoad(function excecuteAfterCompleteLoad() {
    // initialze configuration using init method
    window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.init(config)
      .then(function onSuccess() {
        // after successfully updating configuration, invoke JS Checkout
        window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.invoke();
      })
      .catch(function onError(error) {
        console.log("error => ", error);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please once clear your browser cache and cookies, if the issue still persists please raise a query on Paytm Developer Support